# Django : I want another web page to load inside a div

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am new to Django and I have a simple submit button that is clicked after selecting multiple options in checkboxes. Upon clicking the results show up on a different page. I want the results to show up on the same page itself(below the submit button let's say) or maybe inside a div below the submit button.

Below is the code for your reference:

#template - homepage.html

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'book:homepage.html' %}">
            {{ genre_form }}
            {{ author_form }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md submitB">FILTER IT</button>
</form>
```

#views.py

```
@require_http_methods(["GET"])
  def search_results_view(request):
  genre_choices = request.GET.getlist("genre_choices")
  author_choices = request.GET.getlist("author_choices")
  posts = Post.objects.all()
   if genre_choices:
    posts = posts.filter(genres__id__in=genre_choices)
   if author_choices:
    posts = posts.filter(author__id__in=author_choices)
   return render(request, 'homepage.html',{'posts': posts})
```

#urls.py

```
app_name = 'book'
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
path('results/', search_view, name='post-search-results'),#ignore
path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'), #ignore
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I hope this bit of information will be useful. Right now, the functionality works great but the results show up on a different page. I want the results to show up on the homepage itself and the above code is what I tried but it is not working.

Please help.

Update : As asked, I have added the output in the homepage itself(where I want the result to be but still its not helping)

```
{% for post in posts %}        
    {{ post }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Since you are new to stackoverflow. I have suggestion, Always provide code in question details. For this question add front end(html part) and back end(django view)

Comment: Sorry about that. I have now added the code and extra details. thank you so much. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine! always provide the frontend part where you are passing the data from your views. That might be the problem, use the dictionary `posts` that you have mentioned here in your views to your (frontend) part. You might be using that `posts` elsewhere in the project that's why it renders it to that page.

Comment: I assume what you meant is using posts as an output on the page where I want it to be. I used that on the homepage itself. I have edited my original post and added this bit of code you mentioned. Please refer.